# Where does this formula for complex derivatives comefrom?

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that the derivative formula for a complex function is this limit.

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}=f'(z_0)$$ and I know the Cauchy-Riemann equations but I don't understand how we go from this 
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}=f'(z_0)$$ to this

$$f'(z_0)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}i$$ (I think that is the correct formula.)

How are these two related are C-R used? And when is it okay to use the second one?

Answer (score 1):

Write $z=x+iy.$ Then, if $f'(0)$ exists, one has that (considering only $z=(x,y_0)$)

$$f'(z_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0}\dfrac{u(x,y_0)-u(x_0,y_0)+i(v(x,y_0)-v(x_0,y_0))}{x-x_0}=u_x(x_0,y_0)+iv_x(x_0,y_0)$$ and (considering only $z=(x_0,y)$)
$$f'(z_0)=\lim_{y\to y_0}\dfrac{u(x_0,y)-u(x_0,y_0)+i(v(x_0,y)-v(x_0,y_0))}{i(y-y_0)}=-iu_y(x_0,y_0)+v_y(x_0,y_0).$$ Thus, we obtain

$$f'(z_0)=u_x(x_0,y_0)+iv_x(x_0,y_0)=-iu_y(x_0,y_0)+v_y(x_0,y_0),$$ from where we deduce the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Answer (score 0):

$$f' (z) =\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(z+t) -f(z)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f((x+t)+iy) -f(x+iy)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{u(x+t,y) -u(x,y)}{t}+i\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{v(x+t,y) -v(x,y)}{t}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} (x,y) +i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} (x,y)$$